# Is there something like the PHP function nl2br() for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

Is there stock standard function that does newline to `<br />` encoding in ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is now:

```
public static class StockStandardFunctions
{
    public static string Nl2br(this string input)
    {
        return input.Nl2br(true);
    }

    public static string Nl2br(this string input, bool is_xhtml)
    {
        return input.Replace("\r\n", is_xhtml ? "<br />\r\n" : "<br>\r\n");
    }
}
```

Amended to follow the php spec for nl2br a little more closely (thanks Max for pointing that out).  This still assumes \r\n new lines though...

Comment: It was my impression that nl2br was a lot more robust than this. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: You can use Environment.NewLine to ask the system what it usually uses for newline 0x0D 0x0A (\r\n) or just 0x0A (\n). But then again if text comes from different sources (e.g. online form), you never know. Best to just ditch \r from your text first and then replace all \n with <br />. The xhtml tag is supported by all browsers now, so I would remove that parameter.

Answer (score 6):

All these answers are quite correct, but you should do a `mystring.Replace("\r?\n", "<br />");` to catch UNIX line endings as well, if your source (user input or db) might deliver that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a 'stock standard function' to do this exactly the same as PHP's nl2br() function however the following will do the equivelant:

```
myString.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: If one is very strict, this method call is clearly not "exactly the same" as phps nl2br. For a more detailed specification of what nl2br actually does, see: http://us3.php.net/nl2br - and thats not just for this answer, but for most of the answers so far.

Comment: The question asks 'is there somethig like...' which is different from 'is there something exactly the same'. This solution is 'something like'.

Answer (score 2):

```
mystring.Replace("\r\n","<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something along the lines of:

```
public static string Nl2br(string str)
{
    return Nl2br(str, true);
}

public static string Nl2br(string str, bool isXHTML)
{
    string brTag = "<br>";
    if (isXHTML) {
        brTag = "<br />";
    }
    return str.Replace("\r\n", brTag + "\r\n");
}
```

Here's the function signature from the PHP documention:

> string nl2br  (  string $string  [, 
>   bool $is_xhtml = true  ] )

The PHP function also appends a newline after the break tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in the given answers is that it does not care of an already modified string, so if you pass the modified string again to the nl2br function it will add break tags multiple times.

To solve that problem first I strip any HTML break tags in the source string:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Replaces new lines (\r\n or \n) in an HTML string, 
''' by HTML break tags ("&lt;br&gt;").
''' </summary>
''' 
''' <param name="html">
''' The source HTML string.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="is_xhtml">
''' Optional. True to use "&lt;br /&gt;" XHTML-style break tags 
''' instead of "&lt;br&gt;" HTML break tags.
''' <para></para>
''' Default value: false
''' </param>
''' 
''' <returns>
''' The modified HTML string with line breaks replaced by HTML break tags.
''' </returns>
Public Shared Function NewLineToHtmlBreak(html As String, 
                                 Optional is_xhtml As Boolean = False) As String

    ' \r\n on Windows, \n on Unix systems.
    Dim newLine As String = Environment.NewLine
    Dim htmlTag As String = $"<br>{newLine}"
    Dim xHtmlTag As String = $"<br />{newLine}"

    ' Strip any HTML break tags + newLine in the source string
    ' to avoid replacing them multiple times.
    html = html.Replace(If(is_xhtml, xHtmlTag, htmlTag), newLine)

    ' Replace new lines to HTML break tags.
    Dim nl2brRegex As New Regex("\r?\n", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    Return nl2brRegex.Replace(html, If(is_xhtml, xHtmlTag, htmlTag))
End Function
```